# How to add a T to List<T> where List<T> masquerades as 'dynamic' and T as 'object'?

Tags: c#, dynamic, collections, casting

How would I get change this snippet to correctly add an instance of `A` to a `List<A>`, `B` to a `List<B>`, etc.?

```
// someChild's actual type is A
object someChild = GetObject();
// collection's actual type is List<A> though method below returns object
dynamic list = GetListFromSomewhere(...);
// code below throws a RuntimeBinderException
list.Add(somechild);
```

The exception is thrown because, while the `Add()` is found by the binder, it passes in `dynamic` which fails overload resolution. I prefer *not* to change the above to use reflection, or at least to minimize that. I do have access to the instance of `System.Type` for each of `A` and `List<A>`. The class or method containing the above code is itself not generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to make the binding for the argument dynamic too - so you just need the type of `someChild` to be `dynamic`:

```
dynamic someChild = GetObject();
dynamic list = GetListFromSomewhere(...);
list.Add(somechild);
```

In your previous code, the compiler would have *remembered* that the compile-time type of `someChild` was `object`, and so used that compile-time type instead of the execution-time type. The execution-time binder is smart at only treating dynamic expressions dynamically for overload resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's right so I accepted that, but there's also my own forgetfulness that `List<T>` implements `IList` (the non-generic version):

```
object someChild = GetObject();
var list = (IList)GetListFromSomewhere(...);
list.Add(somechild);
```